# FFMPEG - Chaining more than 2 fade filters causes no fades

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video that fades in and out several times. This is an example that shows the problem.

This command fades a video in from black at frame 20 for 24 frames and then fades out at frame 74 for 24 frames.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=in:20:24, fade=out:74:24" out.mp4
```

I was expecting this next command to do the same, with the addition of another fade in at frame 110 for 24 frames.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=in:20:24, fade=out:74:24, fade=in:110:24" out.mp4
```

However, this produces a video that is completely black.

Is chaining fade filters even possible? Would I have to layer several overlays each containing their own fade in and out in order to get this result or is there a simpler way?

Comment: *this produces a video that does not contain any fades at all* --> do you see source content or all black?

Comment: Source content, it appears identical to the source. Added to the question to clarify, thanks.

Comment: Show the full console output (run with `-report`). I get all black here as I expected.

Comment: Oh crap I explained that wrong. I was originally going to add something about how the alpha=1 flag would give an output identical to the source but I decided to edit it out as I thought it was unnecessary. However, it clearly didn't get fully edited out. It produces a fully black output, sorry.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38166233/5726027